# How to remove cells from UITableView directly?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

is it possible to remove a cell from UITableView directly, with animation? Without changing datasource and then reloading table data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In UITableView you have the method:

```
 (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

There's a similar method to remove a section.

However, you had better have your data model updated just before you call or else scrolling the table may yield odd results!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean here by "changing the datasource" because removing a row is as simple as deleting an object from the array that's populating the table (the array your datasource is using), then reloading the table.

No animation, no datasource swap.

Comment: Understandable enough, once you reach a couple hundred items in the list. You're really gonna want to avoid reloading the entire list, since it takes forever.

Comment: And if you have a cell selected and you would like to remove some items without killing the selection you need to use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.